# AWS Lambda replacing certain characters from attachments of multipart-form data with replacement character(U+FFFD)

Tags: ruby, aws-lambda, multipartform-data, character-replacement

I am using AWS lambda function to receive a multipart request with attachments and upload them to S3.

But Lambda function replaces few characters with the replacement character and so the attachment getting corrupt.

I checked on a PNG file.
sample content: `\x89PNG\r\n\u001A\n\u0000\u0000\u0000`

All the characters are received as they are but `\x89` or in general `\x**` getting replaced by the replacement character(U+FFFD).

I am extracting the attachment `file_str` as a string and writing into a file and then uploading it to s3.

```
File.open(file_path, 'w') do |f|
  f << file_str
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess is the problem is not in writing the file but in the encoding of `file_str`. Whatever is doing the string encoding is forcing it to be valid UTF-8. You need to look earlier in the process

Comment: You are correct. I tried the same with rails and I got the error even before reaching the action in the controller. Error: "Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8"

Answer (score 0):

You need the binary mode on to work with (to write) binary files.

```
#                      ⇓ THIS
File.open(file_path, 'wb') do |f|
  f << file_str
end
```

You try to store the content in UTF-8 and `\x89` is not valid UTF-8.

Comment: Tried this but it's still giving the same corrupt file.

Comment: `file_str` must also have `"BINARY"` encoding.

Comment: But how can I get BINARY encoded file_str in the first place?. The string I am receiving is already corrupt as Ruby couldn't understand some of the characters(So it replaces them with the replacement character ).

Comment: Should I encode the string before saving it to file?